# Cannot register scheduled task for creating system restore points using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to automate creation of system restore points using Powershell (v7.2.6). Following are the commands that I have run:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument 'ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Checkpoint-Computer -Description \"Auto Backup\" -RestorePointType \"MODIFY_SETTINGS\""'

$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -At 9am

$stsettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable
```

These work fine but when I run...

```
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Auto System Backup" -RunLevel Highest -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $stsettings
```

...I get the an error message: `Register-ScheduledTask: The parameter is incorrect.`

Not sure which parameter is incorrect though. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `-Monthly` is not a valid parameter of [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: @boxdog My bad, it was supposed to be `-Weekly`. I have updated the question

Comment: The error should contain more details below the portion you posted, does it offer more insight?

Comment: @DougMaurer Unfortunately it doesn't. This is the entirety of the error message

Answer (score 0):

The below command is wrong. There is no -Monthly parameter in New-ScheduledTaskTrigger. Also what you have specified does not make sense, Monthly 9am??

`$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Monthly -At 9am`

Comment: My bad, it was supposed to be `-Weekly`. I have updated the question